# Slide Down working but Slide up don't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a code that on focus a ul appears with slidedown but when I unfocus it its not slideup with timer just get's out I am also using ui-autocomplete search jquery maybe that's the problem any ideas?

```
$('#search-field').focus(function() {
    $('ul.ui-autocomplete').slideDown('medium');
    $(document).bind('focusin.ui-autocomplete click.ui-autocomplete',function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.ui-autocomplete, #search-field').length) return;
        $(document).unbind('.ui-autocomplete');
        $('ul.ui-autocomplete').slideUp('medium');
    });
});
$('ul.ui-autocomplete').slideUp('medium');
```

Comment: Could you put this in a jsfiddle, it makes it much easier to debug, thanks!

Comment: I am using 1.10.3-jquery-ui.min.js and jquery-1.11.1.min.js they got the problem if I run it without them its working fine but it can't search without them I think its a display:block the problem or something else..

Comment: Can you put this in a jsfiddle?